# Remove or Replace Invoke Delegate C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, invoke, ram

Before all. I'm not so good at this and hopefully you will understand it anyway.
Im making a function in my program where it checks to see if a row in a rtb is highlighted. If not, it highlights it. 
For this to work I had to use different threads to be able to access the rtb from different places. My problem is that it creates a new "delegate"/instance/thread every time the timer refreshes. I would like to remove the old thread/delegate or replace it with the new.
Because now the program crashes after a while. It's a very small program but after 40 sec i reach over 3gb ram usage.

Thanks in advance!
Haris.

Code:

```
private void Timer()//Timer for color refresh
{
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(300);
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Form1_Load);
    aTimer.AutoReset = true;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void RefreshColor()//Refreshing the color of selected row
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        if (richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor != Color.PaleTurquoise)
        {
            HighlightCurrentLine();
        }
    });

}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer();

    RefreshColor();
```

Comment: Your timer is firing off the Form1_Load event which in turn starts up another timer and so on. You only need one timer and you can get rid of the Invoke delegate. Just have the timer start up and every 300ms and check the rows back color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening if i am not mistaken is that you are creating and starting new timers exponentially. So your forms loads, Form1_Load method is called. Form1_Load creates a new timer that when elapsed, will call Form1_Load again. As the old timer not being disposed 2 timers are running now that will both create 2 new timers. 4 timers create 4 new so there are 8, 16, 32 and so on...

Basically what you have to do is call other method on timer elapsed:

```
private void Timer()//Timer for color refresh
{
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(300);
    aTimer.Elapsed += ATimer_Elapsed;//new ElapsedEventHandler(Form1_Load);
    aTimer.AutoReset = true;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void ATimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    RefreshColor();
}

private void RefreshColor()//Refreshing the color of selected row
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        if (richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor != Color.PaleTurquoise)
        {
            HighlightCurrentLine();
        }
    });


}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer();

    RefreshColor();
```

Timer(); is only called ones thus creating only one timer.